# Wignerville of market data

Tags: time-frequency, time-series

I am trying to get some insight into market data, in this case the stock `KO`. Here is the chart:

[image: KO]

If I take the `wignerville` of this, I get nonsense:

[image: wignerville of KO]

If I take `first differences`

[image: diff_KO]

Then take the `wignerville`, I get nonesense:

[image]

What is the correct way to `preprocess` market data so as to feed it into a `Time-Frequency` algorithm and get a reasonable estimate/detecting and decoding of, cycles of localized frequency in the data?

Comment: Using the Wigner-Ville representation for this will always give you nonsense. It's defined to be a $W_a(n,k)$ :-)